# DNS with name.com and Amazon S3

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-s3

I have a website on a bucket in Amazon S3, and recently started to get emails from Google "Googlebot can't access your site". When I go to Webmaster Tools and I try to fetch in fact it doesn't work. Also people in locations different from mine sometimes reported they could not access the website.

Now for curiosity I tried from my terminal:

```
$ host xxx
xxx is an alias for xxx.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com.
xxx.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com is an alias for s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com.
s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com has address yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
```

And when I try with `dig`:

```
$ dig xxx

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> xxx
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 17860
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;xxx.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
xxx.    300 IN  CNAME   xxx.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com.
xxx.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com. 60 IN CNAME s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com.
s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com. 60 IN A yyy

;; Query time: 1514 msec
;; SERVER: 75.75.75.75#53(75.75.75.75)
;; WHEN: Fri Aug 22 12:32:13 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 127
```

It seems OK to me. Why would Google tell me there is a DNS error?

**UPDATE:**

Google also cannot fetch robots.txt, but I can fetch it from my browser.

**UPDATE 2:**

I have a forwarding on the root to the www.* hostname:

```
$ dig thenifty.me

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> thenifty.me
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 49286
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;thenifty.me.           IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
thenifty.me.        300 IN  SOA ns1hwy.name.com. support.name.com. 1 10800 3600 604800 300

;; Query time: 148 msec
;; SERVER: 75.75.75.75#53(75.75.75.75)
;; WHEN: Fri Aug 22 13:32:56 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 88
```

Comment: Why don't you give us the actual domain name so we can take a look? I'm also unclear as to how you got from "Googlebot can't access your site" to "DNS error" - did Google Webmaster Tools tell you it was a DNS issue?

Comment: Yes, the message in the dashboard of Webmaster Tools is "Google couldn't access your site because of a DNS error." The site in question is http://www.thenifty.me

Answer (score 1):

`dig thenifty.me`:

No answer section.

`dig www.thenifty.me`:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.thenifty.me.    299 IN  CNAME   www.thenifty.me.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com.
www.thenifty.me.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com. 59 IN CNAME s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com.
s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com. 59 IN A 176.32.116.11
```

It is likely that Googlebot checked both www and non-www and reported an error due to your lacking records for the non-www variant. This is also likely to be why some users can't get to the site - they leave off the www when they type it in.

Comment: I have a 301 redirect to www.* for the non-www variant, is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: How can you have a 301 redirect in place without DNS records?

Comment: I configured it from the interface of name.com, maybe it's more correct to call it Forwarding?

Comment: If you set up forwarding for the non-www in Name.com, you need to contact their support, because it didn't work. There'd be a DNS record of some sort if it worked correctly.

Comment: I think you're right, there is some problem there: I got a response (see update), but it seems totally wrong.

Comment: That response indicates no records. You'll see the same response for `dig pqoiweurpower.thenifty.me`.

Comment: Ah, silly me, it's missing an answer section.

Comment: I removed the A records from the bare domain, that's why the forwarding was not working. As for Google, it's still not fixed.